# Change part of uiwebview text

Tags: objective-c, uiwebview

I have an uiwebview and i load the followin NSString text

```
 NSString *htmltext=@"Likes: @Amore , @George , @Morfy ...";
```

Then i load it to the uiwebview like this defining a color in hex

```
[wholikes loadData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"<html> <head><style>BODY { font-family: 'Times New Roman'; font-size: 14px; word-wrap: break-word}</style></head><body text=\"#645a49\">%@</body></html>", htmltext] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]
              MIMEType:@"text/html"
      textEncodingName:@"UTF-8"
               baseURL:nil];
```

Is there a way to change part of uiwebview text? I want "Likes:" to be presented in another color.

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply split your string into two and insert them with the appropriate HTML formatting into your format string. Thus

```
NSString *htmltext = @" @Amore , @George , @Morfy ...";
NSString *titletext = @"Likes: "; 

NSString *htmlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:
    @"<html><head>...etc. 
    <span style=\"color:red\">%@</span>
    <span style=\"color:blue\">%@</span>
    ...", 
    titletext, htmltext];

[wholikes loadData:[htmlString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]
          MIMEType:@"text/html"
  textEncodingName:@"UTF-8"
           baseURL:nil];
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use css, just like this:

```
<span style="color:blue;">Links:</span>
```

then the word "Likes:" color is blue.